# Is there a C union functionality in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have some data that is being stored as an `Nx32` logical array. Each row represents one word of UDP data that I'm sending. I'm storing it as a logical array because I could access any word, part of a word, or even across word boundaries. (I.e., I might store a `uint32` as `[array(1, 17:32) array(2, 1:16)]`. Currently I find the data the user wants based on input word position, LSB, and MSB.

The functionality I'm writing into the classes to read to/write from places in the data essentially require that I convert any given MATLAB numeric type or char into its binary form, then store the binary form into the logical array, or vice versa. Basically there's a lot of `num2hex` and other conversions. (Actually, I tried to convert a float to binary using, say,  `dec2bin(hex2dec(num2hex(pi)))` but the output is incorrect!).

In C, a `union` could easily cast between data types. I could write an `int` and read it out as a `float` directly. Is this functionality possible in MATLAB? I do have access to all the toolboxes if that helps.

Comment: All the answers provided help do what I want, but in the end I'm making my own `union_t` object that emulates the behavior I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I not familiar with anything that directly matches with the concept of a union in Matlab, but but it's possible to obtain the same results (using more memory). I believe that you're looking for [`typecast`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html), e.g.

```
x = uint32([1 2 3]);
y = typecast(x,'single')
```

If you need to change the order of the significant bit, use [`swapbytes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html).

*EDIT*: If you want to handle logicals, then you're going to have to use a binary string as a intermediate step. I think that [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) should be fine (no need to go to hexadecimal as far as I can see) and maybe your issue is that you're not providing the optional second argument that indicates how many bits to write?

```
x = dec2bin(22,32)
```

you can convert to logical and flip the bytes with

```
y = x=='1';
y = fliplr(y);
```

You could also possibly look into using [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) from within Matlab, e.g., this for for doubles:

```
x = java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(22);
y = java.lang.Long.toBinaryString(x)
```

Comment: Previous iterations of my code made significant use of `typecast`. In those iterations I was storing my data as 4 `uint8`s instead of 32 `logical`s. This worked well when the user does not try to span word boundaries, but my program is required to allow users to do such a thing. `typecast()` does not work with `logical`s so this solution is out, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Using dec2bin(hex2dec(num2hex(pi))) is not precise, because floating point numbers have large gaps for large numbers and cannot precisely represent integers. One workaround is to split the 64 bit hex string into two 32 bit strings. For example,

```
hexpi = num2hex(pi)
firstbin = dec2bin(hex2dec(hexpi(1:8)));
secondbin = dec2bin(hex2dec(hexpi(9:16)));

% reconstruct
firsthex = dec2hex(bin2dec(firstbin));
secondhex = dec2hex(bin2dec(secondbin));
hexpi_reconstructed = [firsthex secondhex]
pi_reconstructed = hex2num(hexpi_reconstructed)
```

That code should reproduce the same hexadecimal bits.